# DRCSIM head floating?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the out-of-the-box DRCSIM 1.3.1 the head is floating disconnected from the robot. Is there an error in some offset, or will there be more hardware to fill in the gap?
Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/846/drcsim-head-floating?/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The offset is correct, there will be more hardware (mesh) in the gap early-February.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0